# active admin: open a custom page after clicking on an action_item link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, action, activeadmin, custom-pages

I have resource called "section".In edit page of section i have a action item called "upload scores".On click on "upload scores" i want to open a new page which should get the section id as parameter.

```
action_item only: :edit do
  link_to 'Upload Scores' {:id => section }
end
```

This page should contain a form with a "upload xls sheet" button and submit button.On click on "upload xls sheet" button I should be able to upload the sheet.on "submit" i should read it and update the database.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
action_item only: :edit do
  link_to 'Upload Scores', upload_score_path(id: section)
end
```

change `upload_score_path` with your routes

Comment: thank you. how to create the custom page and also uploading an xls sheet. If you can give some example it will be very helpful. I want to know how to do the whole scenario as i am new to ROR

Comment: i helped me to open a new page